# Why is the use of a value between the brackets of an array delete not possible?

Tags: c++

I understand that in modern C++ compilers the length of an array allocated with `new[]` is stored secretly (usually behind) the array so that when `delete[]` is called the compiler knows the array length, but why can we not forgo that entirely and instead be given the option to use `delete[n]` freeing up that memory?

Given that C++ supports the ideal that you don't pay for what you don't use, and that it is generally a good idea to always know what the length of an array is, I don't understand why this feature was removed.

Comment: Are you saying that something like `delete[15] arrname` is a valid, deprecated expression?

Comment: Why use `new[]` and `delete[]` at all when you can just use `std::vector`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the advantage of `delete[n]` would be?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg because arrays use less overhead and are simpler in cases where I don't need to reallocate memory.

Comment: @Acrethaen Are you referring to an extra 8 bytes needed to store the capacity? Because you will need to store the size of the array anyway.

Comment: You could use non-array `new` with a struct containing only a fixed size array and measure the difference. (Note: if the array element type is trivially destructable, many implementations don't bother store the array size when you use array new.)

Comment: @Acrethaen, don't waste your time defending arrays over `vector`s. It's not relevant to your question, *and you're not going to win any converts*.  Please respond to the first comment, by @CharlesBailey. Was `delete a[15]` ever valid?

Comment: Can you explain what number someone might put in the brackes and what the effect would be of various numbers?

Comment: I've replaced "deprecated" with "not possible" in the question title. Apologies if this renders some comments confusing

Comment: @CharlesBailey Unfortunately I can't get my hands on a copy of C++ first edition, and all I can find are some odd statements here and there, but it is allowed (yet warned about on /W4) in MSVC. I was under the impression it used to be delete[15] arr as C++ acted as a wrapper over C and looped through destructors no matter what type they were.

Comment: @Acrethaen, "[I though it] ... looped through destructors no matter what type they were". Incorrect. Focus on writing code that is correct and easy to read and understand. That should be your focus. The good news is that C++ code that is written this way *tends to be optimal already*. That's the whole point of C++.

Comment: Once you have created a vectors with a specific size (that *is* possible you know) then the "overhead" is minimal in most cases. If you want any kind of "dynamic array" (no matter if you only allocate it once or want to extend it) then `std::vector` should always be the default. If the (nearly unmeasurable) overhead is to much (after you measure it!) first *then* should you think of other solutions. And if you want a compile-time fixed-size array, then you should prefer `std::array` first instead of C-style arrays.

Comment: @Acrethaen. What is the warning here? "but it is allowed (yet warned about on /W4) in MSVC".

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I just tested it on MSVC14.0 and it gives the following "warning C4208: nonstandard extension used: delete [exp] - exp evaluated but ignored"

Comment: @Acrethaen, read the warning. As UnholySheep (thanks!) said, the warning tells us that the number inside `[ ]` is ***ignored***. Don't fool yourself, or other readers of your code, that it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically, the most common reason to remove such a feature is either that it is not needed, or that allowing it increases potential of erroneous program behaviour.

However, that logical explanation glosses over a lot of details, which I'll attempt to discuss here.

For a `delete []` expression to work without undefined behaviour, it needs to be able to access the actual length of what was allocated in the corresponding `new[]` expression.   If it doesn't do that, it cannot invoke destructors (assuming elements are a class type with destructor) for every element of the dynamically allocated array.

Let's first assume that the workings of `new[]` stores the allocated length with the memory in a (I'll use your word here) "secret" (i.e. specific to the implementation) manner.   This means there is no real need for the `delete []` expression to supply the length - the implementation can access the correct value, regardless, and use it.   If the `delete []` expression was to provide a length, the implementation can either ignore it (since it has access to the correct value anyway) or check it.  There is little point in checking it, in practice - if the supplied value is incorrect, the implementation can report it (e.g. write a message to `std::cerr`, calling `abort()`) or ignore it (i.e. use the correct value).  Either way, there is little value in checking the length supplied in the `delete[]` expression.

Alternatively, let's assume the implementation does NOT store the allocated length in a "secret" manner.  There are then two possibilities - the supplied length is either correct or it isn't.   If the supplied length is correct, the `delete []` expression works as intended (correct number of destructor calls for array elements, releasing the correct amount of memory to the host system, etc).   If the supplied length is incorrect, the result is undefined behaviour (the implementation cannot detect a problem, let alone correct it and use the correct length).

Now, what should the standard do?   The three possibilities are to require the `delete []` expression to supply a length, to permit the expression to supply a length (i.e. make it optional), or disallow providing a length.

If the `delete []` expression was required to supply a length, it would not be possible to specify anything other than undefined behaviour if the `delete[]` expression supplied an incorrect length.   After all, some implementations would store the correct length in a "secret" location (so they could ignore the supplied length) and others would simply be unable to check if the value is correct (i.e. they will be unable to recover if the `delete []` expression supplied a wrong length).    Developers would be relying on quality of implementation concerns to get reliable behaviour - from some implementations but not others.

If the `delete []` expressions was permitted to (optionally) provide a length, then the implementation would need to squirrel away the correct length in a "secret" location - in order to ensure correct functioning if the `delete []` expression did not supply a length.   In practice, most implementations would then ignore the length provided, and there would be no need for the `delete []` expression to supply it.    However, developers and language lawyers being the pedants they are, there would be numerous debates over whether a length should be provided in the `delete []` expression, whether that length needs to be correct, and the conclusions would be - it doesn't matter.   Such debates might be delightful for pedants, but would be a source of confusion for beginners to C++.

The last possibility is to forbid the `delete []` expression supplying a length.   This has an effect of requiring the implementation to store the length in a "secret" location.  The workings of the `delete []` expression will then access the length, and work as intended.

So the three possibilities above amount to unnecessarily allowing undefined behaviour, causing unproductive debates among developers over what to do or not to do, or the `delete[]` expression always working correctly if given a valid pointer  (where a valid pointer means one that has been obtained from a `new []` expression, is not deleted twice, etc etc).

The last option - disallowing a length being provided in a `delete[]` expression - is the most logical.   And this happens to be what the standard specifies .....

The only trade-off is that some people look at the history (older specifications DID require a length to be supplied in a `delete[]` expression) and ask for an explanation ... which would consume bandwidth or brainpower for the question to be answered.   As has happpened here.   But, the world is never perfect, so we all live with that.

Comment: Aha. At the end you say "(older specifications DID require a length to be supplied in a delete[] expression) ". That's interesting, never knew that.